# How to setup jsdoc for use on machine with poor internet

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, offline, jsdoc

I have some javascript that I have used the sublime jsdoc plugin to comment. I want to produce some documentation from those comments. I am developing this javascript on a machine behind a firewall and very poor internet, so using the command "npm install jsdoc" fails. This machine definitely has node/npm installed.

I have a laptop dual booting linux/windows 10 which I can take to a decent internet connection.

Searching I came across "opichals" workaround:

> ## fetch the package and its dependencies into a local cache folder:
>
> npm_config_cache=./npm_cache npm install express
>
> ## run the 304 HTTP server
>
> node -e "var http = require('http'); var fs = require('fs'); http.createServer(function (req, res) { res.writeHead(304, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); res.end(); }).listen(9615);" &
>
> ## now this will actually install even when the npmjs.org is not resolvable
>
> npm_config_registry=http://localhost:9615/ npm_config_cache=./npm_cache npm install express
>
> ## shut the 304 server down
>
> fg
>   CTRL+C

Source:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1738#issuecomment-10414774

Obviously (?) you can't type all of these commands into a command line. I have tried the steps, generated a cache folder which contains all jsdoc dependencies (and jsdoc).

I moved that cache onto my other computer, span up the http server (which I dont understand either, I assume I run this inside the cache folder?), set npm config "cache" and "registry" parameters to the appropriate locations. But when I try to npm install jsdoc, it cannot find any of the packages.

So I am seeking to answer **how do I go about setting up jsdoc on a machine without internet?**

I would also like to know if I am correct in believing you can install a package + dependencies from a local cache. Or could you copy and paste a node_modules folder from one computer to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: execute "npm install jsdoc". Wherever jsdoc is installed to (usually within the folder that the command was executed - I had messed with some settings so mine was different). That folder will be called node_modules.

I took node_modules to the computer with poor internet. I did not change the name (and this is important!), opened a command prompt within it and I can now simply type .bin/jsdoc --version and the version prints out.

Because I am running executing jsdoc from the node_modules folder, I had to edit jsdoc.js so that the relative path it generated to look for another module was correct:

- Find jsdoc.js (node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc.js) - open with notepad++ etc
- Change line 25 "require('requizzle')" to "require('../requizzle')".

Running jsdoc (had a huge number of warnings but still) generates an output folder within node_modules.

I hadn't realised you could just copy+paste a node_modules folder. I suspect the edit I had to do means I shouldn't do this?